# PNG with white background renders as transparent on mobile Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a PNG with some transparent parts but also with some white parts. On my desktop browser the images renders correctly. But on my mobile device (Motorola G, Chrome) the white parts appear transparent.

why does this happen? how can I solve it and have the white parts show white and not transparent? There is no CSS applied to the image.

Pleace check the logo top-left corner: http://brinquedoteca-xelepeti.com/

Comment: Like I mentioned: There are some parts in the images that are actually transparent.

Comment: Can we have a link to this PNG?

Comment: As far as I am aware there are no browsers that are capable of editing your PNG files for you. Are you _sure_ the same image is being used on mobile?

Comment: Updated link in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

images are different on web browser file is 545901c612cef.png 
while in chrome mobile is 5458fe627564d.png

Comment: Thanks, sry for dumb question ;)